# Selenium::Remote::Driver: Clicking of an anchor element does not work

Tags: selenium

I have the folllowing html code which contains an anchor element which I want to click so that the script specified within this element is invoked.

```
<div class="ToolsContainer">
<a target="_blank" href="checkup.aspx">
<img class="Tools-img" src="/images/tools02.jpg">
<p class="Tools-text center gray"><span class="black_bold Tool">Checkup</span>
<br>Tool area.</p></a>
</div>
```

I first tried the Perl bindings to the Selenium Webdriver with these starments:

```
$elem = $selen->find_element( "(//a[\@href='checkup.aspx'])" );
print STDERR "href: " . $elem->get_attribute('href');
$selen->click();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error while executing command: click: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource.: mouseClick
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'myhost.de', ip: '178.xxx.yyy.zzz', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-042stab127.2', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 313.
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 313.
Since a few links/buttons where accessible for JavaScriptcode in this project, I tried this as well:
$selen->execute_script( 'var xpath = "//a[@href=\'checkup.aspx\']"; var xpathResult = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; xpathResult.click()' );
```

This time the error message is as follows:

```
Error while executing command: executeScript: TypeError: xpathResult is null
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'myhost.de', ip: '178.xxx.yyy.zzz', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-042stab127.2', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 313.
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 313.
```

What is going wrong here? Which changes to the code (I am bound to S:R:D) could possibly make things work?

Comment: Try to add wait for before clicking that webelement

Comment: @AnkurSingh: I wrapped the find_element invocation in wait_until from Selenium::Waiter, but this did not help.